# calling post method of one class from another class's post method

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

```
class LeaveFormHandler(BaseHandler):
  def post(self):
    #form submission code goes here
      #after this code i wanted to call post method of MyleavesHandler class

class MyleavesHandler(BaseHandler):
  def post(self):
        self.write(json.dumps(r))
```

after the form submission code in the above snippet, i wanted to call post method of MyleavesHandler class..
can anyone please help am a newbie

iam using tornado webserver with python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call instance methods of another handler because you can't easily construct one, and even if you could, you need to ultimately call self.write() on the LeaveFormHandler, not the MyleavesHandler.  You need to factor the logic you want to share out into a shareable location, either a common base class or a static function that takes a handler as an argument.

Comment: can you give me a code snippet suggesting the same.please dont mind as am novice to python and tornado

Comment: `def write_response(handler, r): handler.write(json.dumps(r))`.  Then in each post method, call `write_response(self, r)`